# In PHP, While adding events in icalendar through CALDAV protocol, Received unknown HTTP status

Tags: php, curl, caldav, http-1.1, http-status-code-415

I am working on project based on inserting events in icalendar(iPhone) through CALDAV protocol using PHP language
In localhost the code is working fine.. when adding the same code to server using some functions, received unknown HTTP status..

I tried using `dataType:"text/plain"` and also I tried contentType, still not fixed.. I removed ajax function.. directly link to file.. still its showing ame error.. sometimes its shows `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` and `http/1.1 415 unsupported media type`

last request:

```
PUT /rpc/calendars/mediaj11/calendar~722ea7444446*******/.ics HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.mediajenie.com:2080
Authorization: Basic **********
User-Agent: cURL based CalDAV client
Accept: */*
Content-type: text/calendar; encoding="utf-8"
Depth: 1
Content-Length: 556
```

last response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2019 10:10:48 GMT
Server: cPanel
Persistent-Auth: false
Host: mail.mediajenie.com:2080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 3011
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=5e8045144d7823ac82049d0c7ad40247; path=/
Set-Cookie: horde_secret_key=5e8045144d7823ac82049d0c7ad40247; path=/; domain=mail.mediajenie.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: default_horde_view=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=mail.mediajenie.com
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.7
```